# Wildcard on Geoserver SQL View

Tags: geoserver, sql

I have made the following SQL view on Geoserver:

```
SELECT *
FROM areas
WHERE landuse = '%landuse%'
```

This works perfectly fine when I specify the landuse in the URL, for example 'grass'. However when I want the query to return all features regardless the type of landuse I do not know what I have to enter in the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer is to use a [CQL filter in the WMS request](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#cql-filter) to restrict which landuse types are drawn on the map. There is a [full tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html) available to get you going. However in your case it would be something like:

```
http://...../geoserver/wms?....&CQL_FILTER=landuse='grass'
```

when you want to filter by grass or more complex options like:

```
http://...../geoserver/wms?....&CQL_FILTER=landuse='grass' or landuse='trees'
```

Or just leave it off completely to show all types. Note you will need to make sure the URL is correctly encoded for the spaces and = etc.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between CQL Filter and SQL view, the benefit of CQL is that it's SQL Injection-proof? Then why do would anyone use an SQL view?

Comment: You could use a view to join two tables together for example

Comment: Plus CQL works with any datastore

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've overcome this by replacing the whole where clause with a parameter, and then set the default to *1=1*

```
SELECT *
FROM areas
WHERE %query&
```

you can then supply the full clause e.g. *landuse = 'grass'* within the parameter declaration in the URL.

I appreciate this is a slightly unsatisfactory, and there would be more elegant solutions depending on the underlying database.  Are you using PostGIS?

*And I forgot to mention, as @iant point out below, that you should really be using a [CQL Filter](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#cql-filter), unless there's some reason it's not possible to use.*